# Existence of derivative of log(f(x))

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Assume $f(x,a)>0$ is a function (more specificaly, a probability distribution function) with support $x\in[0,\infty)$ and $0<a<1$. We know that $\frac{\partial \log{f}}{ \partial a}, \frac{\partial^2 \log{f}}{\partial a^2},  \frac{\partial^3 \log{f}}{\partial a^3}$ exist on the support. Can we conclude that $\frac{\partial {f}}{ \partial a}, \frac{\partial^2 {f}}{\partial a^2},  \frac{\partial^3 {f}}{\partial a^3}$ exist and is continuous?

**My answer**: We can write $\frac{\partial \log{f}}{ \partial a}, \frac{\partial^2 \log{f}}{\partial a^2},  \frac{\partial^3 \log{f}}{\partial a^3}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial {f}}{ \partial a}, \frac{\partial^2 {f}}{\partial a^2},  \frac{\partial^3 {f}}{\partial a^3}$. Thus, $\frac{\partial {f}}{ \partial a}, \frac{\partial^2 {f}}{\partial a^2},  \frac{\partial^3 {f}}{\partial a^3}$ exist. Since the derivative exist, it means the limit from left and right of each point is equal and therefore $\frac{\partial {f}}{ \partial a}, \frac{\partial^2 {f}}{\partial a^2},  \frac{\partial^3 {f}}{\partial a^3}$ is continuous.

Is this right?

Comment: So presumably $f>0?$

Comment: @zhw. yes, that is true. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making some mistakes. You want to use $\partial \log f/ \partial a = (1/f)(\partial f/ \partial a),$ but that only works if you know already that $\partial f/ \partial a$ exists. But that is what you're trying to show! Try this instead: $f = e^{\log f}.$ Because $e^u$ is infinitely differentiable, you'll find $f$ has as many derivatives as does $\log f.$

Second, why do you think the existence of certain partial derivatives imply they are continuous? They need not be. Review the classic example $u^2\sin (1/u)$ on $\mathbb R.$